# Multiple Markers on google maps v3 not working in loop

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Okay guys and gals, I am having some issues with adding multiple markers. I swear I have searched till my eyes are crossed and I just cannot figure this out.

Here is my code:

```
function initialize()
{
cnt = 0;

var icon = "bullet-red-icon.png";

var mapProp = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(39.8282,-98.5795),
    zoom:5,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"), mapProp);

$("marker", mapxml).each(
    function(i)
    {
        var iwcontent = $(this).find("mname").text() + "<br /><br />";
        iwcontent += $(this).find("mstreet").text() + "<br />" + $(this).find("mcity").text() + " " + $(this).find("mstate").text() + " " + $(this).find("mzip").text() + "<br /><br />";
        iwcontent += "UNITS: " + $(this).find("units").text() + "<br />";
        iwcontent += "UNIT COST: " + $(this).find("unitcost").text() + "<br />";
        iwcontent += "TOTAL FUEL COST: " + $(this).find("fuelcost").text() + "<br />";

        var mlat = parseFloat($(this).find("mlat").text());
        var mlon = parseFloat($(this).find("mlon").text());

        addMarker(iwcontent, mlat, mlon, map, i);
    }
);

$("#d_transmap").show();
$(".t_loader").hide();

}
```

Now I know all the data is there, I have console.logged everything and all seems fine.
However no markers show up at all.

Here is the addMarker function:

```
function addMarker(content, lat, lon, map, i)
{
    var point = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lon.toFixed(6));
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({ position: point, icon: "bullet-red-icon.png", map: map });
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({ content: content });
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
        return function() {
            infowindow.setContent(content);
            infowindow.open(map, marker);
        }
    })(marker, i));
}
```

Now, if I go outside the loop and call this:

```
addMarker(content, 39.8282, -98.5795, map, i)
```

It will spit out a marker! So my initial thought was something is wrong with my lat long data. However I logged all of those, and even logged the markers themselves and it seems to create them. I just do not see them.

What in the world am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Your `addMarker()` function has a couple of problems.

1. The call to `lon.toFixed(6)` shouldn't be there. Just use `lon` directly. Also I suggest using the name `lng` instead of `lon` for consistency with the Maps API terminology.
2. You don't need the fancy song and dance with the function-returning-a-function for the click event listener. You already have a closure here because `addMarker()` is a function. You don't need yet another closure. And you don't need the `i` parameter at all. This isn't preventing your code from working, but it's a lot of extra complication you don't need.

```js
function addMarker(content, lat, lng, map) {
    var point = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: point,
        icon: "bullet-red-icon.png",
        map: map
    });
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({ content: content });
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infowindow.setContent(content);
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
    });
}
```

Update: Zoom all the way out in your test page so you can see Antarctica. Found your missing markers? :-)

(Update 2: Well, sometimes I see the markers there and sometimes I don't. But keep reading...)

Now check the latitudes and longitudes in your XML download, for example:

```
<mlat>-82.753936</mlat>
<mlon>42.675168</mlon>
```

Comment: All those things were put in there for troubleshooting. I tried your code which was similar to my original code and still no go. Same problem, nothing shows up but if I enter the addMarker outside the loop it will show the marker.

Comment: Put your code in a fiddle so people can try it out. If you want a working Google Maps fiddle to start with, you can fork one of mine: http://jsfiddle.net/geary/FCPJM/

Comment: Okay Michael, here is the script and it does not work on there either: http://jsfiddle.net/VAFS001/B8mvP/8/ I am still going to work on it here.

Comment: Load your fiddle in Chrome, open the Developer Tools, and look at the error message. You can click the filename and line number at the right of the error to see where the error is in your code. If you're not familiar with the Developer Tools, [here's a tutorial](http://www.netmagazine.com/tutorials/javascript-debugging-beginners) and [more info from Google](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/). Take some time to really get familiar with these tools; it's one of the best things you can do to find problems faster.

Comment: Also, that error in the fiddle is in a line of code that wasn't in your original question, so there may be other errors to fix after that one. But with the DevTools you will have a much easier time of it.

Comment: I fixed that error, now I do not see any more errors. I am totally stumped on this. Here is the main page for this issue: http://fuel.myvafinancials.com/drivermap.php?id=1411

Comment: OMG!!!! They went in reversed from the geocoder when I imported them into the database. Well now I have some DB work to do. 24 hours later! Thanks Mike for you help, another pair of eyes is sometimes the best thing.

Comment: The sad thing about all this is I am a pilot. And I never noticed the lat lng issue.

Comment: You're not alone. I think every one of us mapmakers has swapped lat/lng a few times! Part of what makes it easy to do is that screen coordinates are normally specified in (x,y) order, but lat/lng is usually in (lat,lng) order, or in other words (y,x).

Answer (score 0):

use below code for multiple marker
variable **arr** is a array of lat long value

```
   function initialize(arr) {

  directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
  geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

  var mapOptions = {     
  };

  var icon = "bullet-red-icon.png";
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_addresses'),mapOptions);

  jQuery(arr).each(function(i){
     if(typeof arr[i] != 'undefined'){  
      var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(arr[i][0],arr[i][1]);
            geocoder.geocode(
                {'latLng': latlng},
                function(results, status) {
                if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                  bounds.extend(results[0].geometry.location);
                  map.fitBounds(bounds);

                   marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    map: map,
                    position: results[0].geometry.location,
                    icon: icon ,
                    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
                  });
                  //google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', toggleBounce);
                  markersArray.push(marker);
                } else {
                  alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: '
                    + status);
                }
              }
          );
     }
  });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

hope this will help you

Comment: Okay, so I will try this out, but where do I put the infowindow at?

Comment: just put this code in script tag & change "map_addresses" to your map div id

Comment: variable arr contain this value [["23.0237795", "72.5855474"], ["23.0345011", "72.5530171"], ["23.0237795", "72.5855474"], ["23.0376011", "72.6030171"]]